# what is the average weight of a male professional cyclist?

Tags: weight, racing

I just want to get an idea of what the ideal weight of a male rider is in the professional races.

Comment: I don't know about averages or "ideal" weights, but a rider's weight is usually listed on their wikipedia pages. There's a good amount a variability, Nairo Quintana is listed as 58 kg, Marcel Kittel as 86 kg, but the median seems to be a little over 70 kg for all-rounders, higher for sprinters and lower for climbers.

Comment: I think your question might be more informative if you asked about Body Mass Index (BMI) which incorporates weight and height.  Tall people weigh more because there's simply more to us.

Comment: It'd also be a function of ride type.

Comment: @Batman No, rider type is a loose function of weight :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about bicycles or riding them

Comment: I don't know what "ideal" weight means but here are the weights and heights of riders in the Tour de France in [1997](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_hUhk9ZVcUAw/RooZ2tBgiyI/AAAAAAAAAEI/rr2UHBlgqQw/s1600/tdf97-bmi.png), [2004](http://anonymous.coward.free.fr/rbr/tdf04-bmi.png), and [2006](http://anonymous.coward.free.fr/rbr/tdf06-bmi.png).

Comment: @R.Chung That's an answer, not a comment.  Good finding btw.

Comment: @andy256 We've always been pretty accepting of questions about professional races and riders. It's not specifically spelled out in the help pages, I don't recall ever closing one in the past. Whether or not we *should* close them might be a good topic for meta.

Comment: @jimirings I was tossing up giving the polite close reason I did or *this question shows no evidence of research, it's a LMGTFY*! And besides, IMO it's trivia.

Comment: Pure climbers are usally small or at least thin, sprinters tend to be big, heavy and muscular, a reason they are nearly always dropped behind the peloton on mountain stages, while 'rouleurs' and TT-specialists are in between. Though there are no general rules and the categories overlap.

Comment: I would add about 5 kg to 10 kg to the weights listed to Tour de France riders for Classics specialists.  Observe that Backstedt won the Paris Roubaix, Hincapie has been second in that race.  Hushovd  won Gent–Wevelgem and the World Championships.  Boonen has won the World Championships and multiple monuments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a site with a chart that lists pro cyclist's height and weight ranges.

Source credit is  http://www.wenzelcoaching.com/blog/cycling-body-weight-chart/

[image]

Comment: Great find - I've inlined the image so that we still have a copy if the remote website vanishes. This does happen. Great first answer though.